# How to get dev tools in built electron app?

Tags: electron

Is it possible to show the dev tools within a built electron app? The executable that I built using `electron-packager` is behaving differently from the app run using `electron` at the command line, and I have no way to see what kinds of exceptions are being thrown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's possible to show the DevTools in a packaged app, just call `someBrowserWindow.webContents.openDevTools()`. If you want a menu item and/or keyboard shortcut to do it then you'll need to create and set your own menu for the browser window using `someBrowserWindow.setMenu(someMenu)`.