# Electron packaged for win32 does not work

Tags: electron

I've been playing around with Electron and AngularJS and built a simple app.
If I run it with electron it works as expected.
After using electron-packager to package the app into a win32 executable It does not work anymore. (Opens white window and that's it).

Is there anyway to see some debug when packaged?
I don't know what's wrong, the only thing that I might have done "wrong" is include some external CDN libraries. Is that allowed in Electron or must I install everything with node?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use CDNs in Electron, your app will end up taking longer to startup and won't work offline. However, that should still work, open up DevTools and have a look ([this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518984/how-to-get-dev-tools-in-built-electron-app) may be relevant).

Comment: Thank you. I had a few errors including some libs that had absolute paths outside of the project. CDN's are not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

To debug effectively in Electron, you have to turn on browser embedded developer tools inside the `main.js` file of your app, then access them once electron launches.  For example, below is some code which will load your app and turn on a menu with a sub-menu that launches developer tools for Chrome (or via the shortcut defined herein as Ctrl-Shift-I for Windows).

```
app.on('ready', function () {
    'use strict';

    var path = require('path');
    var iconPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/app.ico');
    const appIcon = new Tray(iconPath);
    mainWindow = new Window({
        width: 1280,
        height: 1024,
        autoHideMenuBar: false,
        useContentSize: true,
        resizable: true,
        icon: iconPath
        //  'node-integration': false // otherwise various client-side things may break
    });
    appIcon.setToolTip('My App');
    mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000/');

    var template = [
        {
            label: 'View',
            submenu: [
                {
                    label: 'Toggle Developer Tools',
                    accelerator: (function() {
                        if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
                            return 'Alt+Command+I';
                        } else {
                            return 'Ctrl+Shift+I';
                        }
                    })(),
                    click: function(item, focusedWindow) {
                        if (focusedWindow) {
                            focusedWindow.toggleDevTools();
                        }
                    }
                },
            ]
        }
    ];


    var menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);

    mainWindow.focus();

});
```